# Filter values in table X from table Y

Tags: sql, mysql

A simplified example of what i'm trying to achieve:

Table 1

```
FirstName | LastName | Age | Eye Color |
---------------------------------------|
John      | Dunbar   | 30  | Blue      |
Jane      | Austin   | 98  | Green     |
John      | Dunbar   | 21  | Red       |
John      | Dunbar   | 23  | Brown     |
Mr        | T        | ...             |
One       | More     | ...             |
```

Table 2

```
FirstName | LastName |
---------------------|
John      | Dunbar   |
Mr        | T        |
```

So, What I would like to create is Table 1 without all records matching table 2.
In other words, Table 3:

```
FirstName | LastName | Age | Eye Color |
---------------------------------------|
Jane      | Austin   | 98  | Green     |
One       | More     | ...             |
```

I'm not sure what's the best "select" to get there. I'm guessing some smart usage of "join", but not sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table3 - select rows from Table1 which does not present in Table2

```
  CREATE TABLE Table3
  SELECT t1.* from Table1 t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(Select 1 from Table2 t2 
                   WHERE t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName
                     AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName)
```

Table3 - select rows from Table1 which present in Table2

```
  CREATE TABLE Table3
  SELECT t1.* from Table1 t1
  WHERE EXISTS(Select 1 from Table2 t2 
                   WHERE t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName
                     AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from Table1 where FirstName not in (Select Firstname from Table2) and LastName not in (Select LastName from Table2)

This should work